# Mansonry layout responsive gutter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a mansonry-like layout but with elements that have responsive sizes. The sizes are limited though, they can only be multiples of the smalles rectangle. The idea is that I can have 1x1, 1x2, 2x2, 2x1 elements that fit the best place possible in the page.

I saw some questions like this before but the answer was always something unuseful like 'use bootstrap'. I tried bootstrap grid, skeleton grid and many other already. None of them can handle elements that overlap columns.

I'm using Mansonry js library now, and I'm almost there. There is only one glitch that I'm not beeing able to solve. Mansonry for some reason doesn't like when I make a 2x2 element. It breaks the gutter (even when I include the exact gutter size in the elements width).

Things to note, I'm using a variable (percetage) element width and a height based on that width.

My test html part:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
        <!-- Exemplo divisão -->
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 0.20%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}
.gutter-sizer { width: 0.5%; }

.grid-item:before{
    content:"";display:block;padding-top:50%;
}

.grid-item--width2{
    width: 66.5%;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

This is getting me: http://s23.postimg.org/knxbt44xn/gutter.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello, myself.
I solved it. I tested: Masonry, Nested, Skeleton, Boostrap, (Doing manually), (some cms plugins)...

Finally, the answer was: Freewall.
https://github.com/kombai/freewall

This plugin solves nesting and gutter both vertically and horizontally. If you set widths and heights in proportion, it just works. Actually according to my tests, it works with anything you set. Has tons of options too. I love it!

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="freewall">
        <!-- Exemplo divisão -->
        <div class="brick"> </div>
        <div class="brick two"> </div>
        <div class="brick"> </div>
        <div class="brick"> </div>
        <div class="brick tall"> </div>
        <div class="brick"> </div>
        <div class="brick"> </div>
        <div class="brick"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My final js:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wall = new freewall("#freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
                    cellW: 320,
                    cellH: 160,
                    fixSize: 0,
                    gutterX: 5,
                    gutterY: 5,
                    onResize: function() {
                        wall.fitZone();
                    }
    });

    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

The css just sets the width to 33% (66% on wide), and height to 50% on normal and 100% on tall (heighs based on width using padding top).